# Проблема с вызовом метода объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь вызвать метод объекта из другого его метода. Все хорошо кроме такой ситуации:

```
a = {
  fun: function() {
    alert('!');
  },
  click: function() {
    this.fun();
  },
}

jQuery('span').on('click', a.click);
```

Если метод отвечает на событие элемента, то `this` внутри него будет указателем на элемент, вызвавший событие, а не на сам объект. При попытке исполнить код выдается ошибка: `this.fun is not a function`. Как решить проблему?

https://jsfiddle.net/2vv2rd0x/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Luke, use the* **[`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**!

```
a = {
  fun: function() {
    alert('!');
  },
  click: function() {
    this.fun();
  },
}

jQuery('span').on('click', a.click.bind(a));
```